# Check if std::function is std::plus or std::minus

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
bool basicArithmetic(std::function<int(int, int)> func) {
}
```

It should return `true` if `func` is an instance of `std::plus` or `std::minus` but I have no idea how to check.  I can't use `dynamic_cast` because it's not a pointer.

Comment: Check `target_type`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type

Comment: Arithmetic has an *e*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `target()` member:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int f(int, int) { return 0; }
int g(int, int) { return 0; }

void test(std::function<int(int, int)> const& arg)
{
    std::cout << "test function:\n";
    if (arg.target<std::plus<int>>()) {
        std::cout << "it is plus\n";
    }
    if (arg.target<std::minus<int>>()) {
        std::cout << "it is minus\n";
    }

    int (*const* ptr)(int, int) = arg.target<int(*)(int, int)>();
    if (ptr && *ptr == f) {
        std::cout << "it is the function f\n";
    }
    if (ptr && *ptr == g) {
        std::cout << "it is the function g\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(std::plus<int>()));
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(std::minus<int>()));
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(f));
    test(std::function<int(int, int)>(g));
}
```

Testing for types is straight forward. Testing for specific objects doesn't seem to be that simple: although not necessary for the original question, the code also shows how to test for a specific object of a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` has 2 handy members designed for this specific task: `std::function::target_type` and `std::function::target`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: `return func.target == std::plus<int>() || func.target == std::minus<int>();`?

Comment: @Tips48: the `target()` member is a function, i.e., you'll need to call it. It returns a pointer of an appropriate type or null (see the documentation). Since `std::plus<T>` and `std::minus<T>` are types, you can just use these to test if the target type matches.